# How to get a KProperty<*>?

Tags: android, kotlin, datastore

Here's the code:

```
1. private val dataStore: Lazy<ReadOnlyProperty<Context, DataStore<Preferences>>> = lazy {
    preferencesDataStore(Objects.DATA_STORE_NAME)
}
2. val dataStoreValue: ReadOnlyProperty<Context, DataStore<Preferences>> = dataStore.value
3. val dataStoreGotValue: DataStore<Preferences> = dataStoreValue.getValue(requireContext(), "what it wants?")
```

And point 3 causes problem "Type mismatch.Required:KProperty<*> Found:String"

I've tried to do this: "val prop: KProperty<*> = object : KProperty {...

```
            override fun call(vararg args: Any?): String {return "ok"}

            override fun callBy(args: Map<KParameter, Any?>): String { return "ok"}
```

}", and it actually works, but it causes too much redundant code.

Is there a way to receive some random KProperty<*> to shove in the mouth of "dataStoreValue.getValue" to finally get my DataStore, that is already there?

Comment: This code is weird as hell. Why do you pass `ReadOnlyProperty` objects between your components like this? Why do you create a lazy only to compute it just below? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: To simplify the example. I can't call "val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(Objects.DATA_STORE_NAME)"  from onViewCreated because "Local extension properties are not allowed".

Comment: I mean, your code does a very simple thing in a very complicated way. If I don't miss anything, it just passes `requireContext()` to `preferencesDataStore()` to acquire a `DataStore` object. But it does this in two-steps instead of one, it uses lazy constructs without doing anything lazy and it uses property delegators without delegating properties.

Comment: Answering your question: I guess you can pass any property, e.g.: `interface Foo { val foo: String}` and then pass `Foo::foo`. Or even do something like this: `null as KProperty<*>`.

Comment: interface Foo { val foo: String} worked, thanks. And we have the answer. Too bad I can't mark the comment as the answer.
Nope, null as KProperty<*> won't work "NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.reflect.KProperty<*>"